# Prove $ n \left(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|}\right)^{n-1} < \frac{|z_1|}{|z_1|-|z_2|}$ for $|z_1| > |z_2|$

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Let $z_1 , z_2 \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|z_1|>|z_2|$. Prove that $\forall n\ge 2$ we have  $ n \left(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|}\right)^{n-1} < \frac{|z_1|}{|z_1|-|z_2|}$.

I started with induction:

1. For $n=2$ this inequality is ok because $2\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|} <2 <  \frac{|z_1|}{|z_1|-|z_2|}$.
2. Now we check for $n+1$ so: $(n+1){(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|})}^n < \frac{|z_1|}{|z_1|-|z_2|} $ but I cannot prove that such inequality exists ..

Comment: Not sure I believe your argument for 1. What if $z_1 = 3/2$ and $z_2 = 1/2$?

Comment: $(n+1)(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|})^n=n(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|})^{n-1}\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|} + (\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|})^n< (n+1)\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|}\frac{|z_1|}{|z_1|-|z_2|} +(\frac{|z_2|}{|z_1|})^n$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add parentheses around the fraction to remove some ambiguity. Please check if that still matches your intention.

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

The inequality can be proved directly, without induction: With $c = |z_1|/|z_2| > 1$ it is equivalent to
$$
 \frac{n}{c^{n-1}} < \frac{c}{c-1}
$$
or
$$
 c^n > n(c-1)
$$
and that follows from [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality):
$$
 c^n = (1 + (c-1))^n \ge 1 + n(c-1) > n(c-1) \, .
$$